# How to get rid of "This branch is 4 commits ahead" message in a forked GitHub repository?

Tags: git, github

I forked a repo, started pushing some commits and get a strange message on GitHub:

[image: screenshot]

How I can get rid of this message?

Comment: You open a pull request from your main branch to brndnmtthws:main, if it is accepted and merged then your branch will not be ahead and you will get rid of this message. See https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests

Comment: @mkrieger1 Well, the question of whether you want to get rid of your commits was less rhetorical, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

That just means your fork has changes from the repository it was forked from.

Answer (score 0):

When you [fork a repository](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/working-with-forks/about-forks), the fork appears as a repo in your own account. The fork is ahead of the forked repository when you push commits to the fork. And this is what the message says.

When the original repository is ahead of your fork because other changes were merged, you need to pull the changes to your fork. You can sync the fork with the original repo quite easily today using the *Sync button* using the GitHub UI below the green code button (see step 3 on the linked page).

[Synching a fork](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/working-with-forks/syncing-a-fork) is different from getting rid of unwanted commits.

**Going back to the original state by removing commits**

To go back to the state of the fork where it was when you originally forked it (and remove the commits you see your fork being ahead), you have multiple options:

- Delete the repo in your account and fork it again (easy)
- Remove the commits in your fork (more elegant)

**Example**

My fork is ahead by 1 commit (modified the readme for testing):

[image]

1. I cloned my fork to my local computer.
2. I ran `git log` to check the history
3. I removed the commit (you can also use the previous commit ID here instead of HEAD~number) with the command: `git reset HEAD~1 --hard`
4. I used `git push --force` to push the removed commit to my fork.

[image]

Note: `git reset HEAD~2 --hard` will go back 2, and so on.

As you can see, the fork is in sync again (no commits ahead).

[image]